# How to Filter out items from one AngularJs $scope that have been added to another $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am using a select to add items to an `ng-repeat` but I would like the added item to be removed from the select once its been added to the `ng-repeat` `$scope`. Ie. filter out players from the dropdown that have been selected.

How can I achieve that?

```
<li ng-repeat="player in nextfixtureplayers">
    {{ player.name }}
</li>

<select id="players" ng-model="selectedPlayer" ng-change="addGamePlayer(selectedPlayer);"
  ng-options="player.name for player in players | filter:{live:'true'} track by player.$id">
    <option value="">Select player</option>    
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just splice them from the array.

```
$scope.addGamePlayer = function(player) {
    //add to ng-repeat list
    $scope.nextfixtureplayers.push(player);

    //first, find the index of the player
    var i = $scope.players.indexOf(player);
    $scope.players.splice(i, 1); //then remove from array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an option, see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/2890/)

```
$scope.items = [{name:"name1", selected: false},{name:"name2", selected: false},{name:"name3", selected: false}];
    $scope.addItem = function(item){
        item.selected = true;
    }
```

It uses the same collection in both controls (select and ng-repeat).

Anyway, there are a lot different solutions for that and the best one depends on the context.